# Django-filters query params conflict

Tags: django, query-string, django-filters

I am trying to work with filtering db by query params from the link that looks like this:

```
{{url}}/api/books?author="XXX"&from=2003&to=2051&acquired=true
```

I already handled author and acquired params but am stuck with from and to. My filter.py looks like this:

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
      author = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="authors__fullname", lookup_expr="icontains")

      from = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name="published_year", lookup_expr="gte")
      to = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name="published_year", lookup_expr="lte")

      acquired = django_filters.BooleanFilter(field_name="acquired")

      class Meta:
          model = Book
          fields = [
                  "author",
                  "from",
                  "to",
                  "acquired"
                  ]
```

I am looking for a way to assign these query params without overwriting key words (from and to) which is obviously a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define special BookFilter class. This task can simply done on view level. Just define a DateFilter class to filter according to the dates, and the other
type of filters like search by name or order by price can be implemented on view level. **(Make sure your model have a created_at field)**.
Here is an example

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as rest_filters

from apps.yourappname.models import YourModel

from django_filters import rest_framework as rest_filters


class DateFilter(rest_filters.FilterSet):   
  created_at = rest_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()

  class Meta:
     model = YourModel
     fields = ['created_at']

class YourAPIView(ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = YourModelSerializer
  filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter, 
                     rest_filters.DjangoFilterBackend, ]

  filter_class = DateFilter
  search_fields = ['authors__fullname' ]
  ordering_fields = [ 'created_at', ]

  def get_queryset(self):
     dataset_queryset = 
     YourModel.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
     return dataset_queryset
```

When you filter by date, your URL will look like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/yourappname/id/files/?created_at_after=2022-04-19&created_at_before=2022-05-28

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may have same problem:
I managed to create a workaround in which I create copy of querydict, pop() "from" and "to" values and assign them to newly created "from_date" and "to_date" keys.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).